# About Libgdx.How to show my picture from device.(I have the picture path now)

Tags: android, path, libgdx

I want to show my camera take picture on screen.
I have the picture path that is 
"/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180501_155027.jpg"

But I can't show it use`image = new Texture(Gdx.files.external("badlogic.jpg""/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180501_155027.jpg"));`

I know `image = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));`can show the image from assets folder.How can I show picture from my device.
please help me,and give me some suggests thank.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *absolute* type of `FileHandle` if you use *fully qualified paths* like "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180501_155027.jpg".
If you need to read file from SD card you can use *external* type of `FileHandle` but in this case path should be relative from SD card root:

```
Gdx.files.external("/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180501_155027.jpg");
```

Read more about GDX file types [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#file-storage-types)

Comment: I use "Gdx.files.absolute"  to finish my problem.But I will try you say that "Gdx.files.external("/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180501_155027.jpg");".
thank you for your help!About path I think I still have much to learn.